# (sqlite3.OperationalError) table transactions has no column - Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm taking an online course that requires me to build a stock trading website in Python and sqlite. I am getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table 
transactions has no column named purchase [SQL: "INSERT INTO 
transactions (username, symbol, price, quantity, purchase, timestamp) 
VALUES ('Ari', 'ZG', 40.39, 5, 201.95, '2017-12-13 03:58:52.905863');"]
```

If you look at my code below for updating the user's transaction history, you will see that I'm adding the purchase variable to the SQL query which I also have as a column in my database.

```
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
from flask_session import Session
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from datetime import datetime

from helpers import *

# configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# ensure responses aren't cached
if app.config["DEBUG"]:
    @app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
        response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        response.headers["Expires"] = 0
        response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
        return response

# custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")

@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    return apology("TODO")

@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock."""

    # if user reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")
    else:
        # ensure user entered a symbol and shares
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = request.form.get("shares")
        if not symbol or not shares:
            return apology("Must input stock ticker and shares")

        # check to make sure stock is real
        stock = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
        if not stock:
            return apology("Stock does not exist")

        # make sure user inputs valid number of shares
        shares = int(shares)
        if shares <= 0:
            return apology("Shares must be positive integer")

        # select user's cash balance
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])
        cash = float(rows[0]["cash"])

        # total cost of purchase
        purchase = float(stock["price"]*float(shares))

        # does user have enough cash?
        if cash < purchase:
            return apology("You don't have enough money")

        # update user cash
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - :purchase WHERE id = :id;", \
                    purchase=purchase, id=session["user_id"])

        # update user's transaction history
        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (username, symbol, price, quantity, purchase, timestamp) \
                    VALUES (:username, :symbol, :price, :quantity, :purchase, :timestamp);", \
                    username=rows[0]["username"], symbol=stock["symbol"], price=float(stock["price"]), \
                    quantity=shares, purchase=purchase, timestamp=str(datetime.now()))

        # return to index
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

Here is an image of the structure of my transaction database:

[SQL transactions structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3cX6.png)

Can you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dropped the transactions table in my sqlite db and reimplemented it. Now it works.